# Bounded function implies pointwise consistency = uniform consistency over a closed ball?

Tags: probability-theory

Consider a scalar valued function $g_k(\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is a $p \times 1$ vector. Let $w_k$, $k=1,...,\infty$ be random variables with $E[w_k] = 0$ and $|w_k| < M <\infty$.

Suppose that

> **(A1)** $\Theta$ is a closed ball centered at $\lambda_0$
>
> **(A2)** For every $\lambda \in \Theta$,
>
> $$  n^{-1}\sum^n_{k=1} w_k g_k(\lambda) \xrightarrow{p}\ 0   $$
>
> **(A3)** $g_k(\lambda) < M$ for every $\lambda \in \Theta$ and every $k$

In one article I've read, I'm seen it claimed that

> **(1?)** Under A1-A3, consistency in $A2$ is uniform in $\lambda \in \Theta$, that is,
>
> $$ \sup_{\lambda \in \theta} n^{-1}\sum^n_{k=1} w_k g_k(\lambda) \xrightarrow{p}\ 0   $$

However I don't think that's true. I think $A3$ needs to be replaced by the following,

> **(A3')** The functions $g_k(\lambda)$ have the same Lipshitz constant on $\Theta$

Under $A3'$ [we have equicontinuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948656/equicontinuity-if-the-sequence-of-derivatives-is-uniformly-bounded) of the $f_k(\lambda)$, which implies [stochastic equicontinuity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2825853/uniform-consistency-of-a-sum-of-functions-with-random-weights/2825869#2825869) of $A2$, which is enough for uniform consistency.

However, the paper makes other assumptions in the paper, such that

> **(A4)**
>
> $$  n^{-1}\sum^n_{k=1} w_k  \xrightarrow{p}\ 0   $$
>
> **(A5)** Each $w_k$ is either equals to minus one or equals to a constant $c_k$.
>
> **(A6)** The $g_k(\lambda)$ are continuously differentiable in $\lambda$ on $\Theta$. With ${\bf h}_k(\lambda) = \partial g_k(\lambda) / \partial \lambda$, we have
>
> $$  n^{-1}\sum^n_{k=1} w_k {\bf h}_k(\lambda) \xrightarrow{p}\ 0   $$

However, I don't think $A4-A6$ are enough to prove that the consistency in $A2$ is uniform.