# Precompactness criteria for $C^1 [0,1]$ with sum metric

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

I was wondering, what would be precompactness criteria for $C^1 [0,1]$ with metric equal to sum of two sup-metrics, $\rho(f,g) = \rho_{\infty}(f,g) + \rho_{\infty}(f',g')$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subset $A$ of $C^1$ is precompact if and only if $A$ and $A'$ are uniform bounded and $A'$ is equicontinuous. It trivially follows from Arzelà–Ascoli theorem. Equicontinuity and uniform boundness of $A$ in your metric is equialent to equicontinity and uniform boundness $A$ and $A'$ in $\rho_{\infty}$. For proof of equicontinuity of $A$ look here [Equicontinuity if the sequence of derivatives is uniformly bounded.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948656/equicontinuity-if-the-sequence-of-derivatives-is-uniformly-bounded).